# How to import CSV data to table with foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data warehouse type model in MySQL so there's a facts table that is all foreign keys pretty much. I have all the data in CSV files and have imported all of it fine but I can't import to the facts table because "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails".
Most of the answers I've found get it solved with SET foreign_key_checks = 0 but I keep getting the same error, I thought it might be because I'm using the table import wizard instead of LOAD DATA INFILE but that gives me the secure-file-priv error and I've tried everything to solve that without success.

So is there a way to do this? Will it work if I create the tables in a different order? like set the foreign keys in the facts table after I import the data?

edit: I've tried to import the file anyway even though I'm getting errors just because and it imported two rows, I have no idea what this means, every row has the exact same columns filled

Answer (score 1):

just leaving this here in case someone needs a quick fix like I did, you can create the tables without foreign keys, import all data (including to the facts table) and only then add the foreign keys to the table, works fine!
just make sure the data in the columns of the fact table matchs with the data from the table it is referencing, meaning it won't let you import a 99 if the dimension referenced doesn't have a row with 99

Comment: If you refer back to the question, the issue is with the data not with the fact that there are FKs. With your approach, all that will happen is that the fact table will be loaded with invalid data and subsequently trying to re-apply the FKs will fail

Comment: yes, but I still couldn't import the data when the facts table had foreign keys already, might be just a me problem, I did get a few that I couldn't solve with simple solutions I found online

Answer (score 0):

You need to load your dimension tables first and then when you load your fact tables you lookup the dimension tables to get the relevant keys to insert into your fact tables

Comment: I have loaded the dimension tables. I can't import data to the fact table the same way? What do you mean by lookup? Please don't tell me I have to manually fill the fact table 

Comment: Lookup = Join your source data to the dimension tables to get the key(s) of the appropriate dimension records that matches your source record